# Remove blank strings from array with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

How does one remove blank string items from an array in jq?

This is my best guess, but it doesn't appear to work:

**Attempt**

```
echo '["bob","","tim",""]' | jq '[ . [] | if length > 0 then . end ]'
```

**Desired output:**

```
["bob", "tim"]
```

**Error:**

```
. [] | if length > 0 then . end                            
jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at <top-level>, line 1:
. [] | if length > 0 then . end       
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Adding "else empty" gets the right result

```
jq '[ .[] | if length > 0 then . else empty end ]'
```

Consider using select instead.

```
jq '[ .[] | select(length > 0) ]'
```

And since map(x) is equivalent to `[.[] | x]`, we can do this.

```
jq 'map(select(length > 0))'
```